# Why is this JSON invalid using NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, json

I'm new to JSON and don't understand why this is failing. The JSON is valid according to on-line validation tools, but NSJSONSerilization says this the string is invalid. Why is it invalid?

```
NSString* JSON = @"{\"Questionnaire\":{\"questionnaireid\":1,\"modifiedDate\":\"2012-12-28 15:27:00\"}}";

if (![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:JSON]) {
  return nil;
}

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonParsingError];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you did serialization when you already created JSON yourself ?

What you should do:

```
NSData *jsonPayload = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonPayload
 options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: I was thinking backward. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Because a JSON Object must be of type NSArray or a NSDictionary while you are passing a NSString.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

**UPDATE**

You probably want to do this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

Comment: also, dataWithJSONObject returns NSData* not NSDictionary*